# Multiple "Cannot connect to iTunes store" messages on subsequent storekit.init when cancelling transactions -Cordova/Phonegap

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, cordova, in-app-purchase

I'm using this excellent plugin for iOS in app purchases https://github.com/j3k0/PhoneGap-InAppPurchase-iOS

These are consumable items.

Everything is working nicely and I can see the products and purchase them successfully, however there are some strange happenings. It seems that if I initiate a purchase, and then cancel, this canceled purchase will be added to the queue and on restarting the app it will try to complete all these aforementioned canceled purchases. It can get to a point where you have 5 10 or even 20 "Cannot connect to itunes store" messages to click on before you can then use the in app purchase again (depending on how many transactions you have canceled). Important to note it's not just 'cannot connect to store' I purposely entered my password incorrectly and got the 'could not sign in' error which then got appended to this queue of errors also.

Heres the relevant section of the log from xcode that is repeated for each instance

InAppPurchase[objc]: Payment transaction updated:
2014-02-14 13:35:15.737 MyAPP[228:60b] InAppPurchase[objc]: Error 2 Cannot connect to iTunes Store 2014-02-14 13:35:15.738 MyAPP[228:60b] 
InAppPurchase[objc]: State: PaymentTransactionStateFailed
2014-02-14 13:35:15.739 MyAPP[228:60b]

And the code I am using for the In-app-purchase

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);


function onDeviceReady() {
    // Empty
}


function IAPOK() {
    // empty
}

var IAP = {
  list: [ "purchase250", "purchase500" ]
};


IAP.load = function () {



  // Check availability of the storekit plugin
  if (!window.storekit) {
    console.log("In-App Purchases not available");
    return;
  }

  // Initialize
  storekit.init({
    debug:    true, // Enable IAP messages on the console
    noAutoFinish: true,
    ready:    IAP.onReady,
    purchase: IAP.onPurchase,
    restore:  IAP.onRestore,
    error:    IAP.onError
  });
};

IAP.onReady = function () {
    //load all product data.
    storekit.load(IAP.list, function (products, invalidIds) {
      IAP.products = products;
      IAP.loaded = true;
      for (var i = 0; i < invalidIds.length; ++i) {
        console.log("Error: could not load " + invalidIds[i]);
      }
                  IAP.render();
  });
};

IAP.render = function (el) {
    var el = document.getElementById('in-app-purchase-list');
  if (IAP.loaded) {
    var html = "<p>";
    for (var id in IAP.products) {
      var prod = IAP.products[id];
      html += "<p>" +
       "<h3>" + prod.title + "</h3>" +
       "<p>" + prod.description + "</p>" +
       "<button type='button' class='formbutton' " +
       "onclick='IAP.buy(\"" + prod.id + "\")'>" +
       prod.price + "</button>" +
       "</p>";
    }
    html += "</p>";
    el.innerHTML = html;

  }
  else {
    el.innerHTML = "In-App Purchases not available.";
  }
};

IAP.onPurchase = function (transactionId, productId) {

    storekit.finish(transactionId);

    if (productId === 'purchase250'){
        navigator.notification.alert('Thanks for your purchase, your account balance has been updated', IAPOK, 'MyAPP', 'OK'); }

    if (productId ==='purchase500'){
        navigator.notification.alert('Thanks for your purchase, your account balance has been updated', IAPOK, 'MyAPP', 'OK'); }


 };

IAP.onError = function (errorCode, errorMessage) {
  navigator.notification.alert(errorMessage, IAPOK, 'MyAPP', 'OK');
};

IAP.onFinish = function (transactionId, productId) {
    console.log('Finished transaction for ' + productId + ' : ' + transactionId);

};



IAP.buy = function (productId) {

  storekit.purchase(productId);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest commits to the plugin may solve the issue. Failed transactions were queued when "    noAutoFinish: true" was set.